# Apache Giraph Graph Partitioning.... Can a partition p1 resides partially in worker w1 and partially in worker w2?

Tags: giraph

I am newbie in Apache Giraph. My question is related to Giraph graph partitioning. As far as I know, Giraph partition the large graph randomly.... possibly #partitions>#workers in order to load balance. But, my question is, **is #partitions/worker always an integer?** Saying in the ther way,  Can it happen, that a partition (say p1) resides partially in worker w1 and worker w2? Or, should p1 be either in w1 or w2 at entirety?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Partition in Giraph refers to vertex partition not graph-partitions. For example, if a graph has 10 vertices numbered from 1 to 10 then a possible partition would be {1,2. 3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9,10}. Each partition knows where its outgoing edges are pointing. Each worker creates threads for each partition which is assigned to it. The thread iterates over each vertex in the partition and executes compute function. 
So with this information I would say a partition has to reside on a single worker entirely.

Hello @zahorak,

If Giraph implemented Pregel as it is, then as per the Pregel paper it is not necessary to have #partitions == #workers. It says,

> The master determines how many partitions the graph will have, and assigns one or more partitions to each worker machine. The number may be controlled by the user. Having more than one partition per worker allows parallelism among the partitions and better load balancing, and will usually improve performance.

UPDATE: I found the similar question on Giraph user mailing list. The answers given in replies might be helpful. Here is the link to the thread - https://www.mail-archive.com/user@giraph.apache.org/msg01869.html

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK **no**, actually I would have said, `#partitions == #workers`

The reason for partitioning is to handle parts of the graph on one server. After the superstep is executed messages sent to other partitions are exchanged between the servers within a cluster.

Maybe you understand something else under the term partitioning as me, but for me partitioning means:

> Giraph is on a cluster with multiple servers, in order to laverage all servers, it needs to **partition** the graph. And than in simply assings randomly a node to one of the *n* servers. Out of this you get *n* partitions and nodes within each partition are executed by the one server they were assigned to, no other.